# Basic Django, How do I configure this empty path

Tags: django

So, I was trying to run a Django website I found on github [Link](https://github.com/Megatron8010/django-blog/blob/master/mysite/urls.py) but the home page for the site isn't working. It gives the following error

```
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

blog/

admin/

login/ [name='login']

logout/

register/ [name='register']

login/ [name='login']

logout/ [name='logout']

password_change/ [name='password_change']

password_change/done/ [name='password_change_done']

password_reset/ [name='password_reset']

password_reset/done/ [name='password_reset_done']

reset/<uidb64>/<token>/ [name='password_reset_confirm']

reset/done/ [name='password_reset_complete']

The empty path didn't match any of these.
```

Can anybody take a look at the repository and help me out with what's wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
# import re_path

from django.urls import path, include, re_path

# in your urls, you can use re_path to define empty path

re_path('^$', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(next_page='blog:home')),
```

Answer (score 1):

this means that there is no home route with no sub URL like this:

```
 path('', Home.as_view(), name='home' ),
```

so the www.yourdomain.com URL is not handled only the

www.yourdomain.com/blog/ and others in the list, for now, try typing the www.yourdomain.com/blog/ and it should take you to it

updated urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='blog/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(next_page='blog:home')),
    path('register/', RegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('auth/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
```

]

Comment: Thanks I can see its working with www.yourdomain.com/blog/ but how do I make the same page work with just www.yourdomain.com/ ?

Comment: share the urls page and i can tell you for sure but you should be able to change the path('blog/'......) to path('' .....)  where you are replacing the 'blog/' string with an empty string